# How can i print the pattern given below (rhombus shape) in C?

Tags: c

Expected output:

[image]

I have already printed the rhombus shape but I cant get it to print this number pattern (1 232 34543...)
Here is my code.
If anyone can help me I would appreciate it very much.
Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, rows;
    int stars, spaces;

    printf("Enter rows to print : ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    int a;
    stars = 1;
    spaces = rows - 1;

    /* Iterate through rows */
    for(i=1; i<rows*2; i++)
    {
        /* Print spaces */
        for(j=1; j<=spaces; j++)
            printf(" ");

        /* Print stars */
        for(j=1; j<stars*2; j++){
         printf("*");
        }

        /* Move to next line */
        printf("\n");

        if(i<rows)
        {
            spaces--;
            stars++;
        }
        else
        {
            spaces++;
            stars--;
        }
    }

    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You've got the pattern, now work on the numbers.  Make an attempt, then come back with a **specific** question if you get stuck.

Comment: Could you like give me an idea how the number pattern will work?

Comment: To start, can you write a function that takes in the row number, and returns the first digit to be printed on that row?

Comment: Can you work out the *first* number in each row? Then work from there.

Comment: The second function I'd write would take in the first digit to be written on a given row, and return the count of digits needed on that row.

Comment: you also need to find when you're at the middle of the row and decrease instead of increasing. Can even be done already by outputting say '-' instead of '*' past the middle...

Comment: Consider starting loop counters with 0 (not 1). Usually this makes life much easier.

Comment: `% 10` might be useful, particularly if the max number of rows isn't limited to 9.

Comment: Ok ill look into to all of your suggestions

Comment: Do you have a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I did not put my answer to let you figure it out, but since there is already one I show how I did it too. It seems to work. (Only the changed part).

```
        for(j=1; j<stars*2; j++){
         if (j < stars)
            if (i < rows)   // upper left triangle
               printf("%c", '0' + ((j + i - 1) % 10));
            else            // lower left triangle
               printf("%c", '0' + ((j + rows * 2 - i - 1) % 10)); 
         else
            if (i < rows)   // upper right triangle
                printf("%c", '0' + (2 * stars - j + i - 1) % 10);
            else            // lower right triangle
                printf("%c", '0' + (2 * stars - j + rows * 2 - i - 1) % 10);
        }
```

Making a bit more compact and getting rid of the "character mentallity" in the `printf`.

```
        for(char c, j = 1; j < stars * 2; j++) {
          if (j < stars)
            c = i < rows ? (j + i - 1) : (j + rows * 2 - i - 1);
          else
            c = i < rows ? (2 * stars - j + i - 1) : (2 * stars - j + rows * 2 - i - 1);

          printf("%d", c % 10);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are only two parts that need to be changed. (Since other people have posted answers)

Note: the following solution requires some knowledge on the absolute value function.

First, before the forloop, you declare another variable which stores the value of rows

```
int totalRows = rows;
```

then, inside the forloop, change your `printf("*");` to the following:

```
printf("%d",(stars - abs(j-stars) -1 + totalRows - abs(totalRows - i)) %10);
```

Let me break it down into two sections: row wise and column wise.

Row wise:

When we look at each row, we can see that the number is increasing starting at index 0 until it reaches the center (at index stars), then it starts to decrease. This is the shape of an inverted absolute value function shifted upward. The -1 is to account for starting at index 0 instead of index 1.

```
stars - abs(j-stars) -1
```

prints a shape of

[image]

This accounts for the increments and decrements in the rows

Column wise:

When we look at each column, we see a similar pattern: the number increases starting at index 1 until center, then it starts to decrease. Another shape of inverted absolute function shifted upward.

```
row - abs(row - i)
```

This accounts for the increments and decrements in the columns

[image]

When you combine the two together, and take mod 10 (which only keeps the last digit). You get the desired output

```
printf("%d",(stars - abs(j-stars) -1 + totalRows - abs(totalRows - i)) %10); 
//totalRows has the initial value of rows
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found one solution to your problem as below...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, k, x, rows, half_row=1;
    int stars, spaces;

    printf("Enter rows to print : ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    int a;
    stars = 1;
    spaces = rows - 1;

    /* Iterate through rows */
    for(i=1; i<rows*2; i++)
    {
        /* Print spaces */
        for(j=1; j<=spaces; j++)
            printf(" ");

        /* Print numbers */
            if(rows >= i){  /* Print First Half */
                x = i;
                for(k=0;k<i;k++){
                    if(x>=10){
                        x=x%10;
                    }
                    printf("%d", x);
                    x++;
                }
                x--;
                for(k=1;k<i;k++){
                    x--;
                    printf("%d", x);
                    if(x==0){
                        x=10;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{    /* Print Second Half */
                x--;
                for(k=1;k<=i-(2*half_row);k++){
                    if(x==10){
                        x=0;
                    }
                    printf("%d", x);
                    x++;
                }
                x--;
                for(k=1;k<=i-(2*half_row)-1;k++){
                    x--;
                    printf("%d", x);
                    if(x==0){
                        x=10;
                    }
                }
                half_row++;
            }


        /* Move to next line */
        printf("\n");

        if(i<rows)
        {
            spaces--;
            stars++;
        }
        else
        {
            spaces++;
            stars--;
        }
    }

    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Always, Happy Coding :)

Comment: If it is helpful then you can accept and upvote my answer, it will help other people for a trustful answer.

Comment: And I have updated my code, now it will work for any number of rows. Please check it. :)

Comment: Is this solution helped you?